# Multiline error in terraform imported file -> terraform init

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

[image]while running terraform init after doing terraform import for existing GCP infrastructure i am getting

error:-Invalid multi-line string
│ Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a
│ multi-line string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline
│ character or use the "heredoc" multi-line template syntax.

even though if i check the file for which this error is thrown i can see terraform import had "\n" post each line in .tf file yet error comes .

We can edit .tf file if created by us but since its generated by terraform import not sure if its good to update even when there is already \n used .

Terraform v1.3.6
on linux_amd64

i can try heredoc but since there are so many \n i am sure it would mess up

Comment: could you please share the terraform config which was used while import?

Comment: its a huge file  , i can share excerpt

Answer (score -1):

`We can edit .tf file if created by us but since its generated by terraform import not sure if its good to update even when there is already \n used .`

I am not sure what you mean by this. Even while doing import one has to write the terraform config manually beforehand and then run `terraform import ....` command on the respective resource.

However, as you stated the issue is most likely in the `user_data` attribute of the resource. I would recommend using [`templatefile`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile) function for user_data which should avoid your new lines issue out of the box.

You can refer to an example for this at https://github.com/ishuar/terraform-eks/blob/main/examples/private_cluster/eks-ec2-private-jump-host.tf#L262 from me.